# Reference for classification of positive involutions

Tags: reference-request, ra.rings-and-algebras, involutions, central-simple-algebras

An *involution* on a finite dimensional algebra $A$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is an involutive anti-automorphism of $A$. If $\sigma$ is an involution on $A$, we say that $\sigma$ is *positive* if $\mathrm{Tr}_{A/\mathbb{Q}}(x\sigma(x))>0$ for all $0\neq x\in A$.

A theorem of Albert [1] classifies finite dimensional **division** algebras over $\mathbb{Q}$ that admit a positive involution. I know how to deduce the classification of all finite dimensional **simple** algebras over $\mathbb{Q}$ that admit a positive involution from Albert's result, and this is well-known, but I do not know a reference for it. I have only found references to partial classifications.

> Is there a reference for this classification?

One reason this is not in the references I looked at is that when the motivation is the study of Abelian varieties, one can immediately reduce to the case of a division algebra.

[1] Albert, A. A. **On the construction of Riemann matrices. II.**  Ann. of Math. (2) 36 (1935), no. 2, 376–394.

Comment: In the book of Jacques Martinet on lattices, he does mention that "Simple algebras with involution have been classified", referring to Landherr's theorem and the "Book of involutions" by Knus-Tignol-Rost-Merkurjev… but I didn't find the statement in that book.

Comment: @Watson Did he write "with involution" or "with a positive involution"? Algebras with involution are indeed classified in the Book of involutions.

Comment: Yes, it is only about general involutions, but I thought it could have been useful. So I still don't know for positive involutions...